# Combining nth-child(odd) and not() in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a problem to combine the following two CSS functions: nth-child(odd) and not(.not-striped)

HTML:

```
<table class="table-striped">
<tr>
    <th>Header</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Line 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="not-striped">
    <td>Hidden line</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ligne 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Line 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Line 4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd):not(.not-striped) > td,
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd):not(.not-striped) > th {
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/barbuslex/9Zck6/1/

JSFIDDLE2: http://jsfiddle.net/barbuslex/4GLMZ/1/

I would like that the not-striped line is the same color as the top line without interrupt the alternating colors on the next lines.

Ex:

- Header: RED
- Line 1: WHITE
- Hidden line: WHITE
- Line 2: RED
- Line 3: WHITE
- Line 4: RED

My table is dynamic so i can have:

- Header: RED
- Line 1: WHITE
- Hidden line: WHITE
- Line 2: RED
- Hidden line: RED
- Line 3: WHITE
- Line 4: RED
- Hidden line: RED

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: I dont understand what are you tring to achieve. Would you like to explain it in another words?

Comment: @Kasyx i update topic

Comment: Will the not-striped row always be in the same place?

Comment: @ralph.m no, never at the same place and they may have several more

Comment: Given your update, there needs to be some kind of pattern in this. The CSS needs to be able to identify a patter for these to follow.

Comment: ok now i understand, ill try to find some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 2 class .stripped & .not-stripped dont you?

```
<table class="table-striped">
    <tr class="striped">
        <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="not-striped">
        <td>Line 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="not-striped">
        <td>Hidden line</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="striped">
        <td>Ligne 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="not-striped">
        <td>Line 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="striped">
        <td>Line 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS :

```
.striped
{
    background-color:#F00
}

.not-striped
{
    background-color:#FFF
}
```

My Result : 
[image]

JSFiddle : 
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Zck6/4/)

Comment: Given your update, yes but isn't impossible with nth-child and not functions ? (Because i use twitter bootstrap css) I would alternate background color for striped lines.

Comment: In your code you don't alternate background color for stripped lines

Comment: Result image added to answer

Comment: Have you the jsfiddle link ?

Comment: Mohammad's answer looks good. I cannot find solution with using nth-child functions. +1

Comment: Yes but this system requires me to manage the alternation lines with PHP. Isn't possible to do with CSS only ?